# Unable to get $http response

Tags: c#, angularjs

When I make a request using below code my C# method does not get any data:

```
$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : ...,
    data : {
        test : 'hello'
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log('success')
    }, function () {
        console.log('error')
    })
```

In debug mode I'm able to hit the method but no data is passed with the request.

Comment: show your c# method please

Comment: try `data: JSON.Stringify({ test: 'hello' })`. what is test/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common mistake. Your call should look like:

```
$http({ method: 'POST',
        url: ...,
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({ test: 'hello' }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
)
.then(function () { console.log('success') }, 
      function () { console.log('error') })
```

Also don't forget to inject [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

For more in depth explanation -> [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

Comment: What is the common mistake? The missing headers?

Comment: what part of the data is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?