# angular $http.post() and php?

Tags: php, angularjs, http, post

I know there are several posts on SO and on many blogs explaining how to get the JSON data that was sent to be read by php. Some use url-encoding, others file_get_contents.

Anyway, it doesn't work for me. I'm sure there is ridiculously easy explanation for it but my code simply doesn't work (the request is sent, the backend answers but that message is more or less always the same: nothing seems to arrive there !

So in my controller I have :

```
var request_data = {
    firstname: 'Quentin',
    lastname: 'Hapsburg'
  };

$http.post("lib/api/public/blog/post", JSON.stringify(request_data))
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

And in the php file:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);

var_dump($data);
```

The result is `NULL` ! 
Any suggestions on where my error is ???

EDIT: This might have something to do with the rewriting rules but is not a duplicate since the same answer does not solve this question !

Comment: Start by looking at your browser's debugger tools' network inspector and figuring out the exact data being sent to PHP and what the response is. Perhaps your server is replying with a 302 redirect, which would discard the POST data…

Comment: I checked that and unfortunately I don't have any specific errors.

Comment: what kind of url rewriting are you using for this php? slim, nginx, apache?

Comment: Try not stringifying it, but sending it as actual JSON object

Comment: RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^ /app/index.html

Comment: Could the rewriting rules be causing that problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

Answer (score 0):

try using **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

```
$http.post(urlBase, $httpParamSerializer(object), {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
}).then(function(r) {
    callback(r);
});
```

and then php will be able to access to your posted object using $_POST

Comment: Not working either. In this case I get the undefined index error !

Comment: what does var_dump($_POST) return?

Answer (score -1):

Please use this js file. It will work

Index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    sdadasdasd
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope,$http){
    var request_data = {
        firstname: 'Quentin',
        lastname: 'Hapsburg'
    };

    $http.post("test.php", JSON.stringify(request_data)).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```