# Posting JSON objects into MVC Controller C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

JS File

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = [{}];
    $scope.users = {};
    $scope.addfield = function () {
        $scope.items.push({});
    }
    $scope.saveUser = function () {
        $scope.results = [];
        console.log($scope.users);

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Data/MethodTest',

            data:{
                users: $scope.users
            }

        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        });

    }

});
```

HTML Code

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myController">
    <form name="educdetailsform" novalidate>
        <label>Education Details</label></br>
        <button ng-click="addfield()">Add Education</button>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <input type="text" name="empData.qualification[]" placeholder="Qualification" ng-model="users[$index].qualification">
            <input type="text" name="empData.year[]" placeholder="Year of Passing" ng-model="users[$index].year">
            <input type="text" name="empData.percentage[]" placeholder="Percentage" ng-model="users[$index].percentage">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" ng-click="saveUser()" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

.cs Code //
 I'm trying to insert values of the object fetched into database. Before which I've just written code to deserialise the objects. as of now I'm getting just null values passed from the JS//

```
 public JsonResult MethodTest(string jsonData)
         {
             string jdata = jsonData.ToString();
             List<StockAllocate> stockData;
             bool status = false;


                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                stockData = jss.Deserialize<List<StockAllocate>>(jdata);
                 status = true;


             return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
         }
```

Comment: refer [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

Answer (score 0):

By default only complex parameters are resolved from body. You need to add [FromBody] prefix for string.

```
public JsonResult MethodTest([FromBody]string jsonData)
```

But in case if you don't know:

```
public JsonResult MethodTest(List<StockAllocate> jsonData)
```

is also possible.

Comment: [HttpPost]
         public JsonResult MethodTest(List<StockAllocate> jsonData)
         {
            
             bool status = false;
             using (InventoryonlineEntities dc = new InventoryonlineEntities())
             {
                 foreach (var e in jsonData)
                 {
                     dc.StockAllocates.Add(e);

                     dc.SaveChanges();
                 }

              
            
                 status = true;
             }
                
             return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
         }

Comment: I've done the above changes. Still JSON passes null values

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your input parameter in CS Controller, from "jsonData" to "users" (the one you've used in your JS `$scope.saveUser`'s `$http.post` data.

Else, try this below code:

```
$http.post('/Data/MethodTest/', {users: $scope.users})
.success(function(data){
  // Code here
})
.error(function(result){
 // code here
});
```

Also don't forget to decorate your CS function MethodTest with [HttpPost].

```
[HttpPost]    
public JsonResult MethodTest(string users)
             {
                 string jdata = users.ToString();
                 List<StockAllocate> stockData;
                 bool status = false;


                    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    stockData = jss.Deserialize<List<StockAllocate>>(jdata);
                     status = true;


                 return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
             }
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I changed public JsonResult MethodTest(string users) and also the JS code. Still there is no benefit.

Comment: @Test: You may please refer to his post - http://techfunda.com/howto/565/http-post-server-request.   
This will definitely help you. Thanks.