# cant make call to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token from angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, salesforce

I'm trying get access token in my angular app but I get the "400 error bad request" error. From postman there is no problem and I get the token this is in my js code. I removed some info from my code here.

```
return $http(
{
    url: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
    method: "POST",
    data : {
        'grant_type':'password',
        'client_id' : 'jD7TnTNigSlQouxCndKvmuhFoPrT8U5ScDsskdq7A',
        'client_secret' : '6148471690',
        'username' : 'test.com',
        'password':'HPLCGE1rjFyERnD6CE'
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```

Comment: any useful errors in the developer tools console at all

Comment: did u try it by disabling the browser security

Comment: @sachilaranawaka - why would you disable browser security!! That's an irresponsible suggestion to make!! Besides, what browser lets you do that!!

Comment: If I try with exactly that data, the response from the request is `error: "invalid_client_id"`, `error_description: "client identifier invalid"` - what errors do you see in the developer tools network tab for that request?

Comment: I think you may need to use `httpParamSerializerJQLike` check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32507103/2127454

Comment: the data i put here is incorrect. but it works for sure in postman with my correct credentials. from javascript i get error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported

Comment: try removing headers

Comment: Keammoort it worked !!!  httpParamSerializerJQLike  thank you so much !! :)