# angularjs using $http method GET to Phalcon but getting empty params array

Tags: angularjs, phalcon

I'M USING ANGULAR 1.6.2 WHIT PHALCON

```
$scope.selectAction = function(Item){

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'Mycontroller/new',
  params : {Item : Item},
  headers : {'Accept' : 'application/json'}
}).then(function successCallback(res) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available

    console.log("DATOS : "+res.data.res);

    $scope.lista_premisos = res.data.res;


  }, function errorCallback(data) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.

    console.log(data);


  }); }
```

And when I pick up on my controller it does not return anything

```
public function newAction()
```

{

```
//si es una petición get
if($this->request->isGet() == true) 
{

    $this->view->disable();

    $id = $this->request->getPost("Item");

    $this->response->setJsonContent(array('res' => array($id)));
    $this->response->setStatusCode(200, "OK");
    $this->response->send();
} }
```

Also had problems with the angular version.

Something I'm doing wrong, help please.

[IMAGE OF RETURN DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a0c4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and check your browser's response for angular

```
function selectAction(Item) {

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'Mycontroller/new',
        data: Item,
        headers : {'Accept' : 'application/json'}
        })
        .then(
            function successCall(response) {
                console.log("DATOS :  " + response);
                $scope.lista_premisos=response;
            },
            function errorCall(response) {
                console.log(response);  
                });
}
```

Comment: I think I have problems retrieving the data in the phalcon controller, data I send from from angular $http ----

I do not know what is the correct way to receive it in my controller ----

I still get back null :/ 
any other idea

Comment: Maybe send it as POST request? You can't send post data with get request.

Comment: I tried with both post and get but I still get null

Comment: `if($this->request->isPost() == true) 
        {
            $this->view->disable();

            $id = $this->request->getPost("Item");

            $payload['result']      = 200;
            $payload['data']['res'] = $id['Item'];

            $this->response->setJsonContent($payload);
            $this->response->setStatusCode(200, "OK");
            $this->response->send();

        }`

Comment: The way I get it on my controller is wrong  `$id = $this->request->getPost("Item");`  I think it should be otherwise because it does not receive anything

Comment: I would appreciate your answer, and your help too.

Comment: i think you should give a try what @Juri mentioned .

Comment: Also im not sure but shouldn't you use data, not params? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: thats a good point , i had an application where the server side was java spring-boot. if i had to take one response i have used data, according to the documentation. when i had to take several parameter from response , i have used data and an array of pram, which worked fine

Comment: @ALDEAL1993 have you tried anything so far ? have you made it as POST ?

Comment: If I test it as POST, but I do not receive anything in my driver, I do not know what happens, I've been finding out for two days and I can not find an answer

Answer (score 0):

I WAS GOING TO RESIGN, BUT FIND SOMETHING IMPORTANT HERE [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)
IT WAS BY DEFAULT SHIPPING TYPE OF ANGULAR

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

WHAT IS USED BY JQUERY IS

```
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
```

FOR THAT I DO NOT GET RESULT IN MY CONTROLLER, I FINALLY GET MY LATEST CODE

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'mycontroller/new',
      data: "idtable=" + Item,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function successCall(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //$scope.dato = data;
      }, function errorCall(error) {
         console.log(error);
      });
```

GOOD AT LEAST SOMETHING I RESOLVED MY PROBLEM WITH THAT. THANK´S AND EXCUSE ME MY EVIL ENGLISH.