# Request body is empty while sending data to server from Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, body-parser

I'm trying to get data from client side ( in Angular ) to nodejs server.

In Angular I have declared a service.

```
export class AddTaskService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  url = 'http://localhost:3000/tasks';
  posttasks(task) {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.url, JSON.stringify({ task: task }));
  }

}
```

In server I added bodyparser and configured it

index.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

router.js

```
router
    .route("/tasks")
    .post(function (req, res) {
        var taskModel = new taskSchema();
        taskModel.task = req.body.task;
        console.log(req.body);
        taskModel.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({
                message: "nouvProj created!"
            });
        });
    });
```

Using postman with `x-www-form-urlencoded` worked, but in Angular when II send data `req.body` is empty

Edit: 
Here's url network details : 
**General**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/tasks
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 27 May 2018 19:24:57 GMT
ETag: W/"1f-NlZ/5EsK7Z/S3Ze5LQN4AonQQ90"
X-Powered-By: Express
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,ar-TN;q=0.8,ar;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 14
Content-Type: text/plain
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
```

**Request Payload**

```
{task: "klj"}
task
:
"klj"
```

Comment: can you post what you see when you put console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));

Comment: look at the network tab in chrome and determine where your request is going

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs $http.post() does not send data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data)

Comment: ^ How is this a duplicate? The linked question is Angularjs, this is Angular.

Comment: @MattPengelly result of console.log is {}

Answer (score 4):

You can pass HTTP headers as options:

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    })
}
return this.http.post<string>(this.url, task, httpOptions);
```

Comment: the result of console.log is `{ '{"task":"value"}': '' }` while expecting `{"task":"value"}`

Comment: remove your JSON.stringify and send the javascript object directly

Answer (score 1):

```js
createTask(task) {
  const httpOptions= {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json})};
  const json = JSON.stringify(task);
  
  this.http.post(this.url, json, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: you're missing an end quote for  application/json

Answer (score 0):

As @Joshua suggest, But you have to just change a little bit

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    })
}
return this.http.post<string>(this.url, {task, httpOptions});
```

and in your server API you have to fetch data like

```
const data = req.body.task
```